Why does IDA changes functions signatures at some point?
On a PowerPC binary with symbols, when you first open it, the symbols are fine.
For instance: SetLineF2(LINE_F2 *)

But at some point, after adding a few structs, it renames all the methods like so:

It doesn't necessarily occur after first struct has been added.
Any ideas on how to prevent that?

Is it possible that you have disabled function name demangling? BTW: Which IDA version do you use?

Using latest version, I disabled Assume GCC v3.x names and that fixed it :)
